# Why would the update produce this result ` {"email":"try@gmail.com"}` in the database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

when i try to update email column for the user i get a weird input in the database and i don't see why. The output in the email column in the database looks something like this    `{"email":"try@gmail.com"}` instead of just the email

### HomeController

```
 protected function createMail(Request $request)
 {
      $data = request()->validate([
      'email' => 'required',
    ]);

      $id = Auth::guard('web')->id();
      User::where('id', $id)->update(['email' => $data]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` in your case is defined as a result of `->validate()` function, but you need the value of email.

Value can be accessed with `$request->get('email')`.

so your function should look like this:

```
protected function createMail(Request $request)
 {
      $this->validate($request, [
          'email' => 'required',
      ]);

      $id = Auth::guard('web')->id();
      User::where('id', $id)->update(['email' => $request->get('email')]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are updating wrong value and it should be like this

```
protected function createMail(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
      'email' => 'required',
  ]);

  $id = Auth::guard('web')->id();
  User::where('id', $id)->update(['email' => $request->get('email')]);
 }
```

as you see `request->get('email')` instead of `['email' => $data]`